# Annotation processing library for Java

Tags: java

I know everything can be done manually, like in this case using Java reflections api directly. However I want to know if there exist some library to handle annotation processing.

For instance, I have:

```
@Entity
class MyPojo {
 @Id
 private Long id;
 @Attribute
 private String s1;
 // and so on...
}
```

Is there a library that will make it easy to assign values and get values to/from a annotated objects in runtime. Like:

```
Object avalue = AnnotationProcessor.getAnnotatedValue(theObject, Id.class); 
AnnotationProcessor.setAnnotatedValue(theObject, Id.class, 123L);
```

That it handles all the quirks on setting and unsetting field accesses and things like that when doing things manually.

And perhaps have the ability to handle type checking, like in the case of `@Id` above, it should check if the passed argument is Long if not it should fail or handle it properly.

Comment: [Google reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) is one such library. A little on the heavy side, though.

Comment: As to assigning values depending on annotations, [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) can do that, but you have to go through a `Module`